# DNS delegation does not work

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I am quite newcomer to BIND and am trying to understand why is my environment not working.

I have 3 DNS servers, ns1.ixlabs.net, ns2.ixlabs.net and ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.
ns1 and ns2 on ixlabs, are master and slave servers for the ixlabs.net domain.
ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net is the master server for the subdomain plesk.ixlabs.net

This is just an experiment to try to understand how work BIND and DNS and it seems quite simple, but it doesn't work.
When i query dig @ns1.ixlabs.net test1.plesk.ixlabs.net it should run the delegation and ask ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net and retrieve me the ip address associated with the host test1.plesk.ixlabs.net

dig @ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net test1.plesk.ixlabs.net tell me that he can not found ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net

dig @212.129.38.246 (ip address ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net) test1.plesk.ixlabs.net retrieve me the correct info about the host test1.plesk.ixlabs.net

So, what it's happening?

Attached the config files from both of them. Of course they don't have firewalls between them.

```
    $ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
ixlabs.net      IN SOA  ns1.ixlabs.net. postmaster.ixlabs.net. (
                2014091004 ; serial
                28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  ns1.ixlabs.net.
            NS  ns2.ixlabs.net.
            A   212.83.168.145
            MX  10 mail.ixlabs.net.
            TXT "v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:212.83.168.145 mx:mail.ixlabs.net -all"
            SPF "v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:212.83.168.145 mx:mail.ixlabs.net -all"
$ORIGIN ixlabs.net.
billing         IN  CNAME   ixlabsco.roninapp.com.
helpdesk        IN  CNAME   ixlabs.net.
ixsrv01         IN  A   212.83.168.145
mail            IN  A   212.83.168.145
$TTL 60 ; 1 minute
niber           IN  A   91.66.225.104
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
node01          IN  A   62.210.75.148
ns1         IN  A   212.83.168.145
ns2         IN  A   204.145.72.174
plesk           IN  A   212.129.38.246
$ORIGIN plesk.ixlabs.net.
plesk.ixlabs.net.   IN  NS  ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.
ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.   IN  A   212.129.38.246
$ORIGIN ixlabs.net.
www         IN  CNAME   ixlabs.net.
zpanel          IN  CNAME   ixlabs.net.
```

named.conf.option ns1.ixlabs.net

```
    acl goodclients {
        212.129.38.246;
        212.83.168.145;
    localhost;
};



controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

options {

        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        dnssec-enable yes;
    allow-query {
        trusted;
    };
    recursion yes;
        allow-recursion {
                trusted;
        };
    forwarders {
                trusted;
        8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* fixes 100% cpu usage */
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
};

include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
include "/etc/zpanel/configs/bind/etc/named.conf";
include "/etc/zpanel/configs/bind/etc/log.conf";
```

named.conf.local ns1.ixlabs.net

```
zone "ixlabs.net" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/zpanel/configs/bind/zones/ixlabs.net.txt";
    allow-transfer { any; };
    allow-update { key update_key; };
};
```

named.conf.local ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net

```
zone "plesk.ixlabs.net" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/plesk.ixlabs.net.zone";
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

zone plesk.ixlabs.net

```
; BIND db file for plesk.ixlabs.net

$TTL 86400

@       IN      SOA     ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.      postmaster.ixlabs.net. (
                        2014090132  ; serial number YYMMDDNN
                        28800           ; Refresh
                        7200            ; Retry
                        864000          ; Expire
                        86400           ; Min TTL
            )

                NS      ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net. 
                NS      ns2.plesk.ixlabs.net. 

                MX      10 mail.ixlabs.net.


$ORIGIN plesk.ixlabs.net.

test1           IN  A   12.34.56.78 
test3           IN  A   11.33.55.77 
test4           IN  A   22.44.66.88
ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.   IN  A   212.129.38.246
ns2.plesk.ixlabs.net.   IN  A   212.129.38.247
```

named.conf.option ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";

        listen-on-v6 { none; };
        listen-on { any; };

        /*
         * Accept queries from our "trusted" ACL. We will
         * allow anyone to query our master zones below.
         * This prevents us from becoming a free DNS server
         * to the masses.
         */

        /* Use the cache for the "trusted" ACL. */

        /* Only trusted addresses are allowed to use recursion. */

        /* Zone tranfers are denied by default. */

        /* Don't allow updates, e.g. via nsupdate. */
        allow-update {
                none;
        };
        allow-query {
                212.83.168.145;
        };
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion {
                212.83.168.145;
        };
        /* if you have problems and are behind a firewall: */
        //query-source address * port 53;

        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no; # conform to RFC1035

        forwarders {
        212.83.168.145;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        };
};
```

Edited: Due to comment 1, i changed the ns1.ixlabs.net zone. and ran a named-checkconf -zj with this result:

```
zone 10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 16.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 17.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 18.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 19.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 20.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 21.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 22.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 23.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 24.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 25.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 26.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 27.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 28.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 29.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 30.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 31.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone ixlabs.net/IN: loaded serial 2014091004
```

But still not working, ping to test1.plesk.ixlabs.net doesn't resolve neither ping to ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net

I am really totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zone you have delegated is named `ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.`, not `plesk.ixlabs.net.` and it is delegated to `ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.ixlabs.net.` which does not appear to exist. I believe `named-checkconf -zj` should reflect the problem of the unresolvable name.

I assume that instead of

```
ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net. IN NS ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net
```

you meant

```
plesk.ixlabs.net. IN NS ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.
```

Comment: I changed the zone file and updated the main question. Keep not working :(

Comment: @PsySkeletor Querying the server authoritative for `ixlabs.net`, it still doesn't look like the delegation of `plesk.ixlabs.net` exists. However I did see `ixlabs.net. 172800 IN NS ns1.plesk.ixlabs.net.`. Are you sure that the `ixlabs.net` zone actually looks like what is included in the question?